# Allow type declaration with JSHint

Tags: javascript, jshint

I try to validate some server side javascript with JSHint.
Everything looks great so far, but i got problems with a syntax like this

```
var foo:type = bar;
```

The message is

> Missing semicolon.
>
> Expected '(end)' and instead saw ':'.

Is there any way to allow it?

Comment: Are you not looking for TypeScript rather?

Comment: No. In my case the Javascript (that is executed on an server) is only extend with the type.

Comment: but, then it's no longer javascript... TypeScript would allow for just that ;)

Comment: Ahh, ok. But than my question is still open. As is sayed, everythink works just perferct. Only this little thing is a problem. Is there no parameter or something like this i can use in JSHint to suppress this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSHint says it is not valid JavaScript, which is true. You can suppress different warnings about coding style, but it does not (and really, *should not*) allow blatantly wrong code.

Anyway, you should try [tslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint). It was designed for TypeScript.